# TryGetvalue doesn't work if individual items are freed - memory leaks if they aren't

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, firemonkey

I discovered that the Win32 compile of my FMX application has a bug!

The problem is simply that the TryGetValue returns unknown myPOi's if I `{$define FREE_MYPOI}`. If I don't define it (ie. not free each instance of myPOI after it is added to the dictionary), then *Eurekalog* reports memory leaks when the app exits (my POI hasn't been freed obviously).

Most interesting, is that this problem doesn't occur in the Android version of the code with `FREE_MYPOI` defined. (thankfully)

Is my way of adding items to the Dictionary correct? (for Android and Win32 FMX)

Here is the core code:

```
type
  TMyPOI = class(TObject)
  public
    Value: Integer;
    Timestamp: TDateTime;
  end;

...

function TForm2.CreateOrUpdate(username: String; NewTimestamp: TDateTime): String;
var
  poiTimeStamp: TDateTime;
  myPOI: TMyPOI;
  Index: Integer;
begin

  if PoiDict.TryGetValue(username, myPOI) then
  begin
    // existing POI
    Result := InttoStr(myPOI.Value) + ' ' + DateTimeToStr(myPoi.Timestamp);
    poiTimestamp := myPOI.Timestamp;
    // update the Poi's timestamp
    myPOI.Timestamp := NewTimeStamp;
    PoiDict.AddOrSetValue(username, myPOI);
  end
  else
  begin
    // add a new POI
    Index := Random(999);
    Result := IntToStr(Index) + ' ' + DateTimeToStr(NewTimeStamp);
    myPOI := TMyPOI.Create;
{$ifdef FREE_MYPOI}
    try
{$endif}
      myPOI.Value := Index;
      myPOI.Timestamp := NewTimeStamp;
      PoiDict.Add(username, myPOI);
{$ifdef FREE_MYPOI}
    finally
      myPOI.Free;
    end;
{$endif}
  end;

end;

initialization
  PoiDict := TDictionary<string, TMyPOI>.Create;

finalization
  PoiDict.Free;

end.
```

Addendum: This is not an ARC-specific question. It is a question about managing object references.

Comment: Why are you calling `myPOI.Free`?

Comment: No defect in RTL code, your code is broken. With the conditional undefined nothing frees the objects and they leak bit it defined you free them while the dictionary still holds a reference which is even worse.

Comment: I offer a simplification of what you're doing wrong: If you write `TempPOI := TMyPOI.Create; TempPOI.Free; Writeln(TempPOI.Value);` you can ***expect*** that to not work correctly because `TempPOI` is now ***invalid*** because it's ***destroyed***. Conversely if you ***never*** free the object, ***of course*** you have a memory leak. The point is you need to know when to fold 'em; I mean ***correct*** time to destroy the objects. Don't just try random stuff in the hopes something works. Make sure you ***understand*** your code - don't gamble with it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delphi ARC under Firemonkey for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374131/delphi-arc-under-firemonkey-for-windows)

Comment: @nolaspeaker Your question is most certainly is related to ARC and your misunderstanding of it. You make specific reference to how your code reports leaks under Win32 (non-ARC) but doesn't under Android (ARC). And this is all because you're not managing your memory correctly. You could be expecting ARC behaviour in Win32 (Hence why I suggested the poss-dup.) But of course your mistakes may lie in a fundamental lack of understanding about basic resource management. (Hence why it's only ***possible*** duplicate.)

Comment: @Craig Young. That's why I asked the question! (You know there's something wrong, but you don't have enough experience to say what it is exactly) The answer from Dalija has certainly enlightened me and I won't the same mistake again.

Comment: @nolaspeaker But you were arguing that it's not a duplicate; yet clearly the poss-dup has answers that may resolve confusion (for you _or someone else with a similar question_ ). ... Let's not keep going in silly circles. ;)

Comment: I already got my answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't ever `Free` any object you just created and added to any kind of collection. You should transfer ownership over that object to that collection. Following code is inherently broken on Windows - because you are creating dangling references inside dictionary - they will blow on you sooner or later.

```
    myPOI := TMyPOI.Create;
{$ifdef FREE_MYPOI}
    try
{$endif}
      myPOI.Value := Index;
      myPOI.Timestamp := NewTimeStamp;
      PoiDict.Add(username, myPOI);
{$ifdef FREE_MYPOI}
    finally
      myPOI.Free;
    end;
{$endif}
```

You should use `TObjectDictionary` that takes ownership on the values. This will work without the leaks on all platforms.

```
 PoiDict := TObjectDictionary<string, TMyPOI>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
```

Next thing, `myPOI` is an object, so you don't have to add it again with changed timestamp, you can just change timestamp directly - `PoiDict.TryGetValue(username, myPOI)` will just give you the reference it will not create copy of the object.

Corrected code would look like:

```
function TForm2.CreateOrUpdate(username: String; NewTimestamp: TDateTime): String;
var
  poiTimeStamp: TDateTime;
  myPOI: TMyPOI;
  Index: Integer;
begin

  if PoiDict.TryGetValue(username, myPOI) then
  begin
    // existing POI
    Result := InttoStr(myPOI.Value) + ' ' + DateTimeToStr(myPoi.Timestamp);
    poiTimestamp := myPOI.Timestamp;
    // update the Poi's timestamp - this will update object in dictionary 
    myPOI.Timestamp := NewTimeStamp;
  end
  else
  begin
    // add a new POI
    Index := Random(999);
    Result := IntToStr(Index) + ' ' + DateTimeToStr(NewTimeStamp);
    myPOI := TMyPOI.Create;
    try
      myPOI.Value := Index;
      myPOI.Timestamp := NewTimeStamp;
      PoiDict.Add(username, myPOI);
    except
      myPOI.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  end;

end;

initialization
  PoiDict := TObjectDictionary<string, TMyPOI>.Create([doOwnsValues]);

finalization
  PoiDict.Free;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you! Of course, my lack of experience is showing, and your answer fills in the gaps in my knowledge. I don' think this is a specific ARC question, it's a question of understanding how object references work.

Comment: At the very least, on non-ARC systems, the `try..finally` should be replaced with `try..except` to call `myPOI.Free() ` if `PoiDict.Add()` raises an exception.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Why would the Add(...) fail?

Comment: @nolaspeaker adding a value to any container requires allocating memory. That can fail, albeit rare

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are correct, `Add` can fail and in that case `myPOI` would leak. Code corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You are freeing object that stored/added to dictionary. Don't free it! Or, better, use interfaces and forget about manually freeing objects.

P. s. why it's happens? - because objects are stored ***NOT*** by value, it stored by pointer/reference.

P.P.S. I hope you use `TObjectDictionary` and values not leaking.

---

I read again your question and you definitely not using `TObjectDictionary` or manually cleaning up dictionary values, which cause memory leak. You have to free object when dictionary cleaning/free, not after `Add`.